# Excel 2019 How to find a " " (space) in a string and only return those strings that have " " (space)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 2019
Windows 10

I have 26352 cells, each on a seperate row, that contains a text string of various lengths.

Some of the text strings have been entered incorrectly by a previous user and a " " blank space was introduced, some times 2 or more.

I need a formula or VBA function that will look at each text string and IF it contains a " " blank space or spaces then it returns that string. If there are no blank spaces it returns nothing (ignores it).

I have tried the FIND function but to my laymans eyes it requires a LEFT, MID or RIGHT element but I need the WHOLE string to be searched.

For illustration purposes

A perfect string looks like:
Loremipsumdolorsit[amet],(consectetur)_adipiscing_elit

A string with the error looks like
Loremipsumdolor sit[amet],(consectetur) adipiscing_elit

So the formula or VBA would only reurn or display the string with the error.

Thanks.

Comment: `FIND()` does not require the use of `LEFT()`, `MID()` etc. Something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A1)),A1,"")` will do. Even `=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",)=A1,"",A1)`

Answer (score 1):

Why bother doing a find.

Just use substitute() and replace any spaces if they exist. You may need iferror() as well.

Comment: Thanks mike but I have a specific reason for needing to do it the way I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by a work collegue

Assume Cell A1 is the first row & cell with text string to be tested and then copy the formula down the column.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",A1)),A1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",$A1,ROW($A$1:$A$1000)),""),0,0))
```

This will either return a blank value, or will return the character that every space appears on that line, up to a 1000 character string.